# Current Number of Requests per Second with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, performance-monitoring, performance-tuning

I know how to test the maximum number of requests per second with tools like apache bench and httperf.

But is there a way to see the average number of requests per second a live server is currently handling?

I'm hoping for something that is simpler than parsing access log times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the log files has the added problem that they only contain completed requests and not the actively (long) running requests...

Enable the [Status module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) and you can query the web server directly for a live view:

```
<Location "/server-status">
   SetHandler server-status
   Require host localhost
</Location>
```

You can now access server statistics by using a Web browser to access the page `http://your.server.example.com/server-status`

And Apachetop is a nice command line front end to the ServerStatus URL.
https://github.com/JeremyJones/Apachetop